# single update query to update a table without using CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table name Registration and having column as:

```
Id         Name          Gender
1         Sanjay           F
2         Suhana           M
3         Ravi             F
4         Tanya            M
```

Now, i need a query to update Gender M to F and F to M in single query without using CASE.

Comment: Why hate on `CASE` statement ? You can use `IIF` if you are using 2012 or later

Comment: What are the concerns? Performance?

Comment: Why that strange restriction? This is a perfect example when a `case` expression can be used.

Answer (score 2):

I found another option here : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125171/switching-values-in-a-column-with-one-update-statement

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET Gender = CHAR(ASCII('M') + ASCII('F') - ASCII(Gender))
WHERE Gender IN ('M', 'F')
```

Comment: This is the way I've should have done it! (But with an F instead of W.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why don't want to use case statement, you can use `IIF` if you are using sql server 2012+

```
update Registration set Gender = IIF(Gender = 'F','M','F')
```

Comment: @jarlh - yeah right.. Also OP wants to do it in single query so removed it

Comment: OP cant find a simple working solution than this, some question like `i do not want to use case` have no clear reason, It could be  home work assignment from trainers/instructors

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you don't want a `CASE`, but you can find similar result with the following CTE update (assuming that Id is primary key).

```
;WITH FemaleToMale AS
(
    SELECT
        R.Id,
        NewGender = 'M'
    FROM
        Registration AS R
    WHERE
        R.Gender = 'F'
),
MaleToFemale AS
(
    SELECT
        R.Id,
        NewGender = 'F'
    FROM
        Registration AS R
    WHERE
        R.Gender = 'M'
)
UPDATE R SET
    Gender = ISNULL(F.NewGender, M.NewGender)
FROM
    Registration AS R
    LEFT JOIN FemaleToMale AS F ON R.Id = F.Id
    LEFT JOIN MaleToFemale AS M ON R.Id = M.Id
WHERE
    F.Id IS NOT NULL OR M.Id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

First `case` expression would be efficient way to do that, but other way is do that via *look-up* tables

```
select id, Name, a.g2 as Gender 
from table t left join (
    values ('M', 'F'), ('F', 'M')
)a(g1, g2) on a.g1 = t.Gender
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is some question from test or something. So, in order to do this in one statement:

```
UPDATE @DataSource
SET [Gender] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Gender], 'M', 'X'), 'F', 'M'), 'X', 'F');
```

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Gender] CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [Name], [Gender])
VALUES (1, 'Sanjay', 'F')
      ,(2, 'Suhana', 'M')
      ,(3, 'Ravi', 'F')
      ,(4, 'Tanya', 'M');

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource;

UPDATE @DataSource
SET [Gender] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Gender], 'M', 'X'), 'F', 'M'), 'X', 'F');

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]

---

Another way of doing this, instead using `IIF`, `CASE` or `REPLACE` is to convert the `Gender` to number and use `CHOOSE`. Here I am using the `ASCII` function to do this:

```
SELECT *
      ,CEILING(ASCII ([Gender]) % 10 * 0.1 + 1) AS [Char_To_Number]
      ,CHOOSE(CEILING(ASCII ([Gender]) % 10 * 0.1 + 1), 'M', 'F') AS [ValueSwitched]
FROM @DataSource;

UPDATE @DataSource 
SET [Gender] = CHOOSE(CEILING(ASCII ([Gender]) % 10 * 0.1 + 1), 'M', 'F');
```

[image]